# How can I delete a notification channel using flutter local notification?

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I'm using [flutter local notification plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) and I want the user to be able to customize the notification sound and vibration but the plugin's docs says:

> For Android 8.0+, sounds and vibrations are associated with
> notification channels and can only be configured when they are first
> created. Showing/scheduling a notification will create a channel with
> the specified id if it doesn't exist already. If another notification
> specifies the same channel id but tries to specify another sound or
> vibration pattern then nothing occurs.

so I looked up for deleting the channel just to create a new one with the new settings and the docs says that it's a feature in android but I couldn't find any reference on how to do that.
is there's a way to do that, or is there's any another solution?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find an answer or solution about deleting channels, but I tried making a channel for every sound just by using the sound name as an id for the channel, and it worked :).

Comment: Nice Idea :) I will use too.

Comment: By the way there is a function to delete the notification channel in flutter_local_notifications but it doesn't work. So just use your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a proper solution to just delete that channel you want directly
but what i did is just uninstall the app and install it again therefor the channels which gonna be used are those which will be displayed on your phone as the channels appears on your phone when they display a notification.
to Clarify more follow the following steps:

1. remove the functions with the unwanted channels(or just don't call them).
2. Uninstall your app
3. call the notification functions with the channels you want
4. install the app again
5. once the notification is displayed you will find its channel in your app settings